# print to a network printer using PHP

Tags: php, printing, lpr

is it possible to print directly to a network printer with PHP using LPR or something similar?

any pointers?

thanks.

Answer (score 12):

**Sure is. If you are on Linux do use LPR.**

```
exec("lpr -P 'printer' -r 'filename.txt'");
```

[More on LPR commands](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Printing-Usage-HOWTO-2.html).
Take a look into LPR docs. You can easily show the print-queue and more from PHP.

---

**If you are on Windows use print**

```
exec("print /d:LPT2: C:\filename.txt");
```

[More on print syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772773(v=ws.10).aspx)
Or take a look into [this guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc782930(v=ws.10).aspx) that has a deeper explanation of command-line printing.

Comment: for windows is there any options\

Answer (score 0):

//[reader path] /t [pdf path][printer]-Print the document with designated printer

```
exec(" \"$prAddr1\" /t $val  \"$prAddr2\" ");
```