# printing over network from PHP app

Tags: php, linux, printing, cups, network-printers

I have a set of printers connect over a network with Static IP assigned to each printer.

Now i have a PHP web application running on a linux server which needs to send print jobs, to these printer over the network.

Is this possible using lpr or cups and how do i go about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [print to a network printer using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722805/print-to-a-network-printer-using-php)

Comment: This might help you.http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the LPR Printer class from here:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2540-PHP-Abstraction-for-printing-documents.html

Example:

```
<?php 
include("PrintSend.php");
include("PrintSendLPR.php");

$lpr = new PrintSendLPR(); 
$lpr->setHost("10.0.0.17"); //Put your printer IP here 
$lpr->setData("C:\\wampp2\\htdocs\\print\\test.txt"); //Path to file, OR string to print. 

$lpr->printJob("someQueue"); //If your printer has a built-in printserver, it might just accept anything as a queue name.
?>
```

Comment: I would have given you +1, but since the question specifies Linux and your example code uses a Windows directory path, I'm not sure. Can you confirm that this class works in Linux?

Comment: @spudley thanks for the information will have to test the same with my network printer. I was also having a look at google cloud print which looks promising.

Comment: @Spudley - The creator of that class didn't mention any specifics about Windows. So it must work on Linux too. Since I don't know or work on Linux, that directory path is all I understand.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll give you your +1 ;-) I don't have time to check the class for myself as the moment though.

Answer (score 5):

This question has been asked before. See [print to a network printer using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722805/print-to-a-network-printer-using-php)

The answer given that time was `exec("lpr -P 'printer' -r 'filename.txt');`

However, the answer was never accepted so not sure whether the OP found it helpful; it certainly looks like it ought to do the trick, but it's not quite a direct and easy method of doing it from within PHP.

A number of other resources I found were also recommending variations on this approach.

Digging a bit deeper, I see PHP has got a Printer module in PECL. However it's only for Windows, and looks like it's not well maintained. But in case it helps, the link it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.printer.php

I think the answer ultimately is that PHP isn't really designed for this kind of thing, and doesn't have built-in functionality to do it. But since you can shell out to external commands using `exec()` and similar, it shouldn't be too hard to get it working, albeit not quite ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Try [PHP::PRINT::IPP](http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/)

It worked perfectly for me.

Basic Usage

```
 <?php
  require_once(PrintIPP.php);

  $ipp = new PrintIPP();                        
  $ipp->setHost("localhost");
  $ipp->setPrinterURI("/printers/epson");
  $ipp->setData("./testfiles/test-utf8.txt"); // Path to file.
  $ipp->printJob();                                                          
?>
```

[Reference](http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/usage)

Answer (score 0):

i was also doing research on this...and i think the below written code can help you in handling printer in linux

```
<?php
$printer = "\\\\Pserver.php.net\\printername");
if($ph = printer_open($printer))
{
   // Get file contents
   $fh = fopen("filename.ext", "rb");
   $content = fread($fh, filesize("filename.ext"));
   fclose($fh);

   // Set print mode to RAW and send PDF to printer
   printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
   printer_write($ph, $content);
   printer_close($ph);
}
else "Couldn't connect...";
?>
```

Comment: printer_open is a windows only php extension call